# ui autocomplete validate extra blur events

Tags: jquery

I have the validation for autocomplete working.

http://skoizumi.com/autocomplete/index.html

```
var ac = $( "#searchtext" ).autocomplete({
                source: "testdata.php",
                minLength: 2,
                select: function( event, ui ) {
                console.log( '3');                      
                },
                close: function( event, ui ) {
                    console.log( 'closing.' );
                }
            });


            jQuery.validator.addMethod("contractorName", function (value, element) {


                var result = false;
                var contractorName = $("#searchtext" ).val();

                //validating the specified field has a valid name

                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/autocomplete/return2.php",
                    async: false,
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        'searchtext': $( "#searchtext" ).val()
                    },
                    complete: function(test){
                        res = JSON.parse( test.responseText );
                        console.log( res );                         
                        result = res.result;
                    }
                });

                return result;
            }, "Specified Contractor doesn't exist");
```

I made it so that when you select "European Nightjar" from the list or type the same thing, it should validate and return true, otherwise it should display an error message saying "Specified contractor doesn't exist."

However, if you have invalid data in the textbox and select from the list it returns error because validation takes place before selecting from the list.

Is there a way so that validation doesn't have to happen when selecting from the list?

Comment: if my answer helped , click accept, if it didn't add comments so we can better help, people may be reluctant to add answers when you have accepted 0%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is from the jQuery demo site:

```
     $( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
        select: function(event, ui) { ... }
          });
```

add a different function for select:  , select fires when you choose from dropdown , 
instead of just putting console.log( '3');  validate the text here

Comment: I already have set a rule for this field in the validation so that manually input data will be validated "contractorName: true". If I can skip the validation when it was selected from the list that would be great. Only thing I can think of is to set a flag when the autocomplete list is shown and don't validate anything before it is closed.